# Unity android resolution

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

So, I've just begun to develop in Unity for Android (2d game). I already did some search on the net, but I didn't found anything.

How can I set up an Unity UI, to be addictive to the Android Multiple screes resolutions ? When I test in Unity it works fine, but when I install on different phones, the characters are disappearing, the whole UI just blow up

Any idea ?

Comment: Please start tagging your Unity game engine questions with `unity3d` instead of `unity`. Thanks! (The `unity` tag is for the .NET dependency injection container.)

Comment: @JoxTraex I've rolled back your tag edit that re-adds the `unity` tag. Please read the tag wiki for `unity` as well as my comment above. Thanks.

Comment: ah, sorry ! My fault, thanks for telling me ! Can you introduce the unity2d tag please ? Because it's a 2d game, not a 3d! Whatever in this case ?

Comment: Yep, the Stack Overflow gods have deliberated that unity engine questions get tagged `unity3d` (there was a time when Unity provided tools only for 3D games). So now the tag `unity3d` gets used for all unity engine game questions, whether they are 2d or 3d. It's definitely a bit of a misnomer, but it's the way tagging has worked for a while, so everyone kind of just goes with it! Personally I would prefer if the `unity3d` tag were renamed to something like `unity-engine`, but it might cause some confusion to those who have been using the `unity3d` tag since it was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Canvas Scalar](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html). The Canvas Scaler component is used for controlling the overall scale and pixel density of UI elements in the Canvas. This scaling affects everything under the Canvas, including font sizes and image borders.

[image]

- You would set the UI Scale mode to Scale With Screen Size.
- Once you do that, you will see the Reference Resolution X and Y field. The X is the width and Y is the height of the Screen you are designing the game for.
- Set the Screen Match Mode to Match Width or Height so as to scale it dynamically.
- Set the Match factor to 1 or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

you can use scale with screen size to fit your UI and make sure your UI need to set the Rect Transform of your UI like button, text , etc... and if you use scale with screen size in canvas , also need to set the resolutions of canvas , like 1920X1080 by default or like 6:19 or 19:6 , try more to fit your phone size and text it if your change to diff size the UI will change too or not . last thing is all UI need to change the size of it , as if you alr made it , u will see the UI should be overlay. so just make sure all UI is alr set to right Rect Transform and resolutions .